# Symfony 5.2 mock service disappear in second request

Tags: symfony, mocking, phpunit

I used Symfony 5.2 and I need to mock service method which execute send request to stripe payment system, obviously don't need to execute it when tests executing, so I faced with problem with that, when request was send more then one time

config/services_test.yaml:

```
App\Service\StripeService:
    public: true
    lazy: true
```

My test class

```
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Document\User;
use App\Service\StripeService;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as SymfonyWebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class WebTestCase extends SymfonyWebTestCase
{
    private ?string $accessToken;

    protected ?KernelBrowser $client;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = static::createClient();

        $mockStripeService = $this->getMockBuilder(StripeService::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mockStripeService
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('createCustomer');

        $this->getContainer()->set(StripeService::class, $mockStripeService);
```

When first request was executed and was called another request in the same test function mock was replaced to the original class, why ?

Mock behaviour correct, mock service replaced original

```
$this->postJson('/api/register', $userDetails);
```

Before called mock service still present in container

```
$this->postJson('/api/login', [
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            'password' => 'IncorrectPassword'
        ]
    );
```

but inside second request by some reason mock disapear and appear original service class

Answer (score 4):

It's been a while since this question was asked... I had the same problem and looked here for help. Going through the Symfony's code revealed what is actually going on.

Inside the `KernelBrowser` there is a property called `$hasPerformedRequest` that is set to `true` once the first request was performed. When you try to perform the second request this flag causes the kernel to be rebooted. The way  to work around this is to reboot the kernel yourself, set the mock you want and disable client from rebooting the kernel for your next request.

I have expanded your example in a way that would work as you wanted it.

```php
namespace App\Tests;

use App\Document\User;
use App\Service\StripeService;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\KernelBrowser;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Test\WebTestCase as SymfonyWebTestCase;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;

abstract class WebTestCase extends SymfonyWebTestCase
{
    private ?string $accessToken;

    protected ?KernelBrowser $client;

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        parent::setUp();
        $this->client = static::createClient();

        $mockStripeService = $this->getMockBuilder(StripeService::class)
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();

        $mockStripeService
            ->expects($this->once())
            ->method('createCustomer');

        $this->getContainer()->set(StripeService::class, $mockStripeService);

        $this->postJson('/api/register', $userDetails);

        // Reboot kernel manually
        $this->client->getKernel()->shutdown();
        $this->client->getKernel()->boot();
        // Prevent client from rebooting the kernel
        $this->client->disableReboot();

        // Set your mock again
        $this->getContainer()->set(StripeService::class, $mockStripeService);

        // Perform the second request
        $this->postJson('/api/login', [
            'username' => $user->getUsername(),
            'password' => 'IncorrectPassword'
        ]);
    }
}
```